# Add a transaction fee for each time a function is called

Tags: solidity

currently I'm writing my first contract in Solidity.
Now I have a function which looks like this:

```
function sellEnergy(uint kwh) public {
    coinAccount[msg.sender] += (kwh * kWh_rate);
}
```

What I want to do is that everytime this function is called, the user who calls it, should pay a fee of a few cents to the owner. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a fee, check `msg.value` and either `throw` (or `return`) if the fee isn't met.  Example of a fee of 0.001 ether:

```
function sellEnergy(uint kwh) public {
    if (msg.value < 0.001 ether) { throw; }
    coinAccount[msg.sender] += (kwh * kWh_rate);
}
```

Using `throw` is recommended so that any other changes made to your contract are also reverted: it keeps your contract state clean.  (People who don't pay the minimum fee, will lose all their gas though.)

---

A modifier can usually be helpful, so that functions that require a fee are labelled more clearly.  Example of a modifier that's been given the name `requiresFee`:

```
contract SomeTest {
    // state variables ...

    modifier requiresFee(uint fee) {
        if (msg.value < fee) { throw; }
        _
    }

    function sellEnergy(uint kwh) public requiresFee(0.001 ether) {
        coinAccount[msg.sender] += (kwh * kWh_rate);
    }
}
```

If the fee is dynamic, the modifier could be modified like:

```
contract SomeTest {
    // state variables ...

    modifier requiresFee() {
        if (msg.value < computeFee()) { throw; }
        _
    }

    // returns the fee in units of Wei
    function computeFee() internal returns (uint) {
        // compute the fee and return it
    }

    function sellEnergy(uint kwh) public requiresFee() {
        coinAccount[msg.sender] += (kwh * kWh_rate);
    }
}
```