# What is best practice for adding a fee to charge for a function call?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to create a function that charges a user for calling the function. I came across an old example here and I am wondering what the currenct best practice is?

[Add a transaction fee for each time a function is called](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/add-a-transaction-fee-for-each-time-a-function-is-called)

I have a modifier and a simplified function as shown below but it doesn't seem to charge a fee when I test it through metamask and check on etherscan, the transaction goes through normally but without the 0.02 eth fee. Is there something I am missing here?

```
    modifier requiresFee(uint fee) {
        require(msg.value == fee);
        _ ;
    }

    function simple() requiresFee(0.02 ether) payable external {

      owner.call.value(0.02 ether).gas(20317)("");

     // other parts of the function 

    }
```

Thank you